# Dealing with timezone dates in MongoDB and pymongo

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I do not seem to be able to query records and get what I expect. For example I am searching

```
today = datetime.datetime.today()
past = today + timedelta(days=-200)
results = mongo.stuff.find({"date_added": {"gt": past}}, {"id":1})
```

I have the following date specified in MongoDB:

```
"date_added": {
        "$date": "2016-04-19T18:47:54.101Z"
    },
```

But I get no results! Is this down to the timezone which appears in the MongoDB date which is screwing things up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just a typing error:

Try with the following code:

```
results = mongo.stuff.find({"date_added": {"$gt": past}}, {"id":1})
```

You forgot about the $ sign in $gt.

Comment: Ah yes! Gets me all the time!

Answer (score 1):

Use an aware datetime object (with timezone info).

```
# E.g. with UTC timezone : 
import pytz
import datetime

today = datetime.datetime.today()
past = today + timedelta(days=-200)

pytc.utc.localize(past)

results = mongo.stuff.find({"date_added": {"gt": past}}, {"id":1})
```

To use a different timezone to localize, try something like `pytz.timezone('US/Mountain')`

P.S. you'll need `pip install pytz`

Comment: I did try this - any variants - but sadly did not work.